# Como paralelizar um sapply com tabela

Tags: r, paralelismo

Consigo realizar o sapply sem problemas, mas não consigo paralelizar. No script original tenho mais de 9.000.000 de linhas e por isso é inviável continuar sem a paralelização.

```
dfteste<-data.frame(c(1,1,1),c(1,1,1),c(1,1,1))
apteste<-sapply(1:3,function (x) {paste(dfteste[x,], collapse="-")})

library(parallel)
cl<-makeCluster(4)
apteste<-parSapply(cl,1:3,function (x) {paste(dfteste[x,], collapse="-")}) #nao funciona
stopCluster()
```

Obrigada.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que o objeto `dfteste` está presente em somente um dois 4 ambientes criados por `makeCluster()`.
Ou seja, você cria o objeto no ambiente atual, depois cria outros 3 ambientes no qual `dfteste` é inexistente.

**Possível solução**: você pode exportar o objeto `dfteste` aos ambientes criados utilisando a função `clusterExport()`:

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(4)
dfteste <- data.frame(c(1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 1))
sapply(1:3, function (x) {paste(dfteste[x, ], collapse = "-")})
# [1] "1-1-1" "1-1-1" "1-1-1"

clusterExport(cl, "dfteste")
parSapply(cl, 1:3, function (x) {paste(dfteste[x,], collapse = "-")}) # funciona
#[1] "1-1-1" "1-1-1" "1-1-1"

stopCluster(cl)
```